# SQLAlchemy create object in one line?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and in Django or other languages it's possible to create, populate, and commit an object in one line.

`Foobar.objects.create(x=0, y=1)`

Is it possible to do the same in SQLAlchemy? I always have to do the following.

```
foobar = Foobar(x=0, y=1)
session.add(foobar)
session.commit()
```

Would an autocommit solve this?

Comment: You could create a mixin class with a `create` method that does this, and have all your models inherit from it - this is basically what Django is doing.  But fundamentally this is about different architectural patterns.  Django (and Ruby on Rails, and many other frameworks) uses an [active record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern - "Save as you go", if you will.  SQLAlchemy uses a [Unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern, which is more like "make changes to all your models, then save them all at the last minute".

Comment: So if the Django / Active Record pattern better suits your application, perhaps you are better off using a framework that implements it rather than trying to make SQLAlchemy behave as you would like?

Comment: @snakecharmerb make your first answer the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a mixin class with a `create` method that does this, and have all your models inherit from it - this is basically what Django is doing. But fundamentally this is about different architectural patterns.

Django (and Ruby on Rails, and many other frameworks) uses the [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern - "Save as you go", if you will. SQLAlchemy uses the [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern, which is more like "make changes to all your models, then save them all at the last minute"